# How can I edit a binary file under Windows by scripting

Tags: windows, perl, scripting, hex

I've got some technical files produced by a scientific device.
From time to time, these recorded files get corrupted and we have to do some hexadecimal modification by hand.

I'm wondering how I could automate it. I was thinking of Perl, as I've got some knowledge in that, but even if I manage to read the offset of interest, I don't know how to write the new value.

I've got two things to do:

1. Write at offset 4 the size of the file minus 8
2. Count the number of "TRCKfmt" pattern, which is 5452434B666D74 in hex, then write it down at offset 5C (92) in hex value.

I've tried to use `sysread` and `syswrite` on a filehandle, but I can't get through the different steps.

Maybe Perl is not a good option, I don't know how to sort it out.

Here is my actual script:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use diagnostics;

use Fcntl qw(:seek);

my($fh, $filename, $byte_position, $byte_value);

$filename      = "MYFILE.tac";
$byte_position = 4;
my $filesize = -s $filename;
    print "Size: $filesize\n";
    
    
open($fh, "<", $filename)
  || die "can't open $filename: $!";

binmode($fh)
  || die "can't binmode $filename";

sysseek($fh, $byte_position, SEEK_CUR)  # NB: 0-based
  || die "couldn't see to byte $byte_position in $filename: $!";

sysread($fh, $byte_value, 1) == 1
  || die "couldn't read byte from $filename: $!";

printf "read byte with ordinal value %#02x at position %d\n",
     ord($byte_value), $byte_position;
```

Comment: Re "write at offset 4", Just to be clear, you want to overwrite what's already there?

Comment: @Sinan Ünür, That's not true. If he's trying to overwrite parts of the file, he can just seek and just print the bytes the need to be changed as he's trying to do. It's just a little more work to do it that way.

Comment: Yes, `<` would have to be changed to `<+`

Comment: Thank you all for your answer. Indeed, i want to overwrite the actual value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working code based on Ikegami's answer:

```
#!c:/Perl64/bin/perl.exe
use warnings;
use strict;
use diagnostics;


my $dir = 'MYDIRECTORY';

opendir DIR, $dir or die "cannot open dir $dir: $!";
my @files = glob "$dir/*.tac";
closedir(DIR);

foreach(@files){
  my $qfn = $_;

my $file;
{
   open(my $fh, '<:raw', $qfn)
      or die("Can't open \"$qfn\": $!\n");

   local $/;
   $file = <$fh>;
}

{
   my $packed_length = pack('V', length($file) - 8);

   substr($file, 0x0004, length($packed_length), $packed_length);
}

{
   my $num_blocks;
   ++$num_blocks while $file =~ /TRCKfmt/g;
   my $packed_num_blocks = pack('V', $num_blocks);
   substr($file, 0x005C, length($packed_num_blocks), $packed_num_blocks);
}

{
   open(my $fh, '>:raw', $qfn)
      or die("Can't create \"$qfn\": $!\n");

   print($fh $file);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make it easy on yourself and just load the whole file in memory.

```
my $qfn = "MYFILE.tac";

my $file;
{
   open(my $fh, '<:raw', $qfn)
      or die("Can't open \"$qfn\": $!\n");

   local $/;
   $file = <$fh>;
}

{
   my $packed_length = pack('N', length($file) - 8);
   substr($file, 0x0004, length($packed_length), $packed_length);
}

{
   my $num_blocks;
   ++$num_blocks while $file =~ /TRCKfmt/g;
   my $packed_num_blocks = pack('N', $num_blocks);
   substr($file, 0x005C, length($packed_num_blocks), $packed_num_blocks);
}

{
   open(my $fh, '>:raw', $qfn)
      or die("Can't create \"$qfn\": $!\n");

   print($fh $file);
}
```

You didn't say in what format the number should be stored. I assumed they are 32-bit unsigned integers in big-endian byte order.

Comment: So, i gave a try and it's not working as it should. The script is giving the good answer but it's in the wrong direction. I'll do a screen capture to explain http://hpics.li/e69f97f  @ikegami do you have an idea about that point ?

Comment: hey hey, seems that the pack should be in V instead of N, i will do some trials, but seems that's ok

Answer (score 1):

Let's create a file full of 0 bytes:

```
C:\...\> perl -E "binmode STDOUT; say qq{\0} x 32 for 1 .. 4" > test
C:\...\> xxd test
00000000: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000010: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000020: 0a00 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000030: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000040: 000a 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000050: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000060: 0000 0a00 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000070: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000080: 0000 000a                                ....
```

The program below reads offsets and replacement bytes from the `DATA` section. You might want to put those in an external file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Fcntl qw(:seek);

@ARGV or die "Need filename\n";
my ($file) = @ARGV;

open my $fh, '+<:raw', $file
    or die "Cannot open '$file': $!";

while (my $edit = <DATA>) {
    next unless $edit =~ /\S/;
    my ($offset, $value) = map hex, split ' ', $edit;
    seek $fh, $offset, SEEK_SET
        or die "Failed to seek to '$offset': $!";
    print $fh chr($value)
        or die "Failed to write new byte '$value' at offset '$offset': $!";
}

close $fh
    or die "Failed to close '$file': $!";

__DATA__
0 64
8 65
10 61
18 64
20 62
28 65
30 65
38 66
40 20
```

After running the program:

```
C:\...\> xxd test
00000000: 6400 0000 0000 0000 6500 0000 0000 0000  d.......e.......
00000010: 6100 0000 0000 0000 6400 0000 0000 0000  a.......d.......
00000020: 6200 0000 0000 0000 6500 0000 0000 0000  b.......e.......
00000030: 6500 0000 0000 0000 6600 0000 0000 0000  e.......f.......
00000040: 200a 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000   ...............
00000050: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000060: 0000 0a00 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000070: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000080: 0000 000a                                ....
```

Comment: Thank you but the DATA is not constant, therefore, i need to define the value each time, by measuring size of the file and the number of occurence of the pattern